# Powershell Select-String output

Tags: powershell-3.0

Let's say that the Root Domain name is `contoso.com`

When I run this script it gives me an output along the lines of:

`xxxxxx :                                        contoso.com`

*The "xxxxx" represents some characters, including the file name.*

What do those characters mean, and how can I make it so that I only get "contoso.com" as the output, without the characters in front of it?

#### Information

I am using the following powershell script to obtain information:

`Get-ADDomain >> ./log.txt`

From all of the information that `Get-ADDomain` gives me, I want to extract the Root Domain name, so I use `Select-String` to get it out of the text file, as follows:

`$domain = Select-String -Path ./log.txt -Pattern "RootDomain"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that `xxxxxx` gives you the file name and the line number.

Once this said you can retreive `RootDomain` if it exists in the returnes object using

```
$(Get-ADDomain).RootDomain
```

You just have to understand that PowerShell *Cmdlets* returns objects with properties and methods. `$(Get-ADDomain)` execute the CmdLet `Get-ADDomain` and `.RootDomain` returns the value of the property `RootDomain`

Comment: So, to store the RootDomain in a variable, that would be: $var = $(Get-ADDomain).RootDomain

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and `$()` is not required, just `(Get-ADDomain).RootDomain` is enough.
or the PowerShell way is `$Domain = Get-ADDomain | Select-Object -ExpandPropery RootDomain` .